# Debugging with PowerShell (or Command Prompt)

Tags: c++, powershell, debugging, command-prompt

I am working on a project with multiple compiled .exe files. They are mostly compiled in C++, but we also have JavaScript, XML, XSD, and XSL files. Debugging JavaScript is fairly straight forward since I can easily open the debugger tool on the browser. However, I am unsure how to debug the .exe files compiled in C++.

Since I am on a windows operating system, is there a way to use PowerShell (or Command Prompt) to debug the files? I've compiled the files in debug mode in Visual Studio (I'm assuming that is required). This is not a project that can be debugged in Visual Studio.

An example on debugging a simple program such as "Hello World" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"... I've compiled the files in debug mode in Visual Studio..."_ and _"...This is not a project that can be debugged in Visual Studio..."_ does not make sense - please explain ?

Comment: You need the debug symbols and visual studio needs to know where to find them assuming you aren't the one who built the tools from source. You need the `.pdb` files those executables were compiled with.

Comment: visual studio is the best tool for the job, if you can't launch the processes from visual studio attach to the running processes instead

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on .exe files, so there could be something I'm missing, but generally speaking if you're compiling C++, they're being compiled to machine code - just a step above binary. You won't be able to see the functions, variables, classes, etc. because it's all basically binary now. Compilation is an irreversible process - you can't get the original C++ code back.

JavaScript that's shipped to the browser is different in that browsers expect actual JavaScript code, rather than something compiled (though you can still compile JavaScript for an operating system with something like Node.JS).

If you're trying to change those executables, you'll need the original source code.

Comment: _"...I've compiled the files in debug mode in Visual Studio..."_ it looks like OP has all they need ... not sure what the  problem is.

Comment: If the problem executables are causing issues in another solution, VS won't debug those automatically unless you add the symbol file paths of the problem tool to the global config. My C++ is a bit rusty these days but if OP has the `.pdb`s they should be able to at minimum attach the debugger to the problem process while it's running with breakpoints. There should also be a way to map source code if you have it to an attached debug process but it's been too long and I can't recall how.

Answer (score 0):

No, PowerShell can't be used to debug binary files.
It can only debug PowerShell scripts.

If you compile your applications to produce outputs that can be used for debugging, then it's another matter.